# Types of artificial intelligence with good results

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, algorithms, artificial-intelligence

I have been looking into artificial intelligence for some time now. I am wondering what branches are still in active research and have some good/interesting results.

The two that I have looked in so far are Neural networks and Evolutionary algorithms.

What others are there?

Comment: This is asking for a summary of the state of an entire field; that is asking for too much in my view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since "good" is a *relative* term, "good results" is a *very ambiguous* criterion. In addition, as @Nick Cox mentioned in his comment, it's impossible to cover the entire AI field, even if "good results" criterion would have a clear interpretation.

Therefore, I think that, instead of a *summary*, it makes sense to present the **state of AI research** (in terms of *width* rather than *depth*) with examples of most popular *streams of research* and their *applications* (which is what I believe you are actually asking about).

With that **goal** in mind, *artificial intelligence (AI)* encompasses the following *streams of research* (my **taxonomy**, based on ["The AI Book"](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu) - *Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach* by Stuart Russell and Peter Norvig):

- **Intelligent agents**
- **Search** algorithms and solutions, which include classical search for solutions to problems, local search (optimization), online search
- **Game theory** (aka *decision theory* or, in AI parlance, *adversarial search*)
- **Constraint satisfaction problems**
- **Planning** algorithms and solutions
- **Knowledge representation** (*ontologies*, *taxonomies*, *semantics*, *reasoning*)
- **Knowledge engineering** (*propositional logic*, *first-order logic*, *inference*)
- **Knowledge and reasoning under uncertainty** (traditional and Bayesian *probability statistics*, *probabilistic reasoning*, *decision making*)
- **Machine learning (ML)** (supervised, unsupervised and reinforcement *statistical learning*, including *artificial neural networks* and *evolutionary algorithms* that you mentioned; *knowledge-based learning*; *probabilistic learning*)
- **Communication** algorithms and solutions (*natural language processing*, including *text classification*, *information retrieval* and *information extraction*, *machine translation*, *speech recognition*)
- **Perception** algorithms and solutions (image and object *recognition*)
- **Robotics** (*perception*, *planning* and *moving*)

The above is just a **high-level** *taxonomy* of *AI research*, that I took liberty to re-arrange partially to better match co-joining domains. *Sub-domains* in parentheses do not represent an exhaustive list, but I've tried to select the most popular and active *research streams* to the best of my knowledge.

**UPDATE:** Just ran across the following **fascinating** (and **scary**) *TED talk* by Jeremy Howard on *advancements* and *current state* of AI/ML (as well as potential *social and economical problems*, associated with the above). I'm thinking about submitting a question on this to *StackExchange*. Highly recommend to watch and think/discuss: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4kyRyKyOpo.

Comment: What kind of question are you thinking of submitting?

Comment: @Andrey: A question, prompting discussion on potential social, economical and otherwise not purely technical problems, associated with advancements in AI field as well as potential solutions to those problems. Probably, worded very similar to the above.

Comment: In this case, please also watch "Humans need not apply", https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Pq-S557XQU

Comment: @Andrey: Thank you for the link, just finished watching - excellent (and scary) video, similarly to the TED Talk one I've referred to. I think that it makes sense to base the discussion on both videos, as they're very similar in the essence and the message they deliver. I will wait a bit to (hopefully) hear more feedback on my idea, which may include what is the best site for such question - Cross Validated or Data Science.